# How to update the old Google Analytics with New google analytic 4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

Is there an option where I can upgrade my old google analytics with the new UI (web and app) or they have completely different function.

I have data in my existing google analytics, events created in it.

When I try to make a new analytics from firebase it create a new property or a new account and no data shows in the new analytics. How can I have the new analytics upgrade with all my existing data or I have to update the website with new code.

[image]

**OLD Google Analytics**

[image]

**NEW GOOGLE ANALYTICS**

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ or https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

These are **two completely different systems**, using a different data model collection (`sessions and pageviews` vs `users and events`).

Here you can find instructions to set up a Google Analytics 4 property (formerly known as an App + Web property) alongside your existing Universal Analytics property: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9744165?hl=en

The documentation said:

> By connecting, you'll be able to take advantage of future upgrade
> tools to assist with other configurations

This confirms that this functionality probably still rolling out. So, until that moment (we don't know when it will be and we don't know how it will migrate), the configuration of Google Analytics 4 (App+Web) must be done by hand.

Here you can find the best practices for setting up ecommerce data collection in Google Analytics 4 properties: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10119380

Comment: Can't see an option to 
In the Property column, select the desired Universal Analytics property..
Click Upgrade to GA4.

Comment: In italian the documentation (the one I have read) there is not that step, I think it is either a typo or an anticipation of a future feature. As far as I know until yesterday (before App+Web became Google Analytics 4) there was no way to migrate tracking from Universal Analytics. As I anticipated, these are two different paradigms for which the configuration is to be done by hand.

Comment: The documentation said 'By connecting, you'll be able to take advantage of future upgrade tools to assist with other configurations'. This confirms that this functionality probably still rolling out. So, until that moment (we don't know when it will be and we don't know how it will migrate), the configuration must be done by hand.